Distance in Grassmann Manifolds between 2 samples of different datasets
I have a question about the paper 'Domain Adaptation as Optimal Transport on
Grassmann Manifolds' by Long et al.
In the paper, they use distance on Grassmann Manifolds to define a cost function for an optimal transport problem, which they use to adapt a labelled dataset to an unlabelled dataset in the context of unsupervised learning.
This is the part that I don't understand:

My question is: if I understand correctly, $X_{Gs}$ and $X_{Gt}$ are points in the Grassmann Manifold. So distance can be defined between $X_{Gs}$ and $X_{Gt}$,  the datasets themselves. How can a distance on a Grassmann Manifold be defined between samples from $X_{Gs}$ and $X_{Gt}$?
Thanks in advance!
